# RSA to DER anomaly

Tags: openssl

I have a private key in PEM format and when i run a openssl asn1parse on it i get the following:

```
    0:d=0  hl=3 l= 159 cons: SEQUENCE
    3:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE
    5:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   16:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL
   18:d=1  hl=3 l= 141 prim: BIT STRING
```

However if i convert this PEM to DER, and do a openssl asn1parse again, I lose that wrapper and the resulting file size is a bit smaller.

How can i convert the RSA PEM to DER, while keeping the above wrapper?

Comment: How are you converting it now?

Comment: openssl rsa -inform pem -in key.pem -outform der -out key.der

Comment: Can you show us the PEM header for the input file?

Comment: Do you mean in hex? Because if not isnt the above post the header?

Comment: No. The PEM file is a text file that contains a header, base64 encoded DER data, and a footer. The asn1parse command is just decoding the base64. I'm interested in the PEM header. It's a line that starts with "-----BEGIN " followed by some more text. Depending on what exactly the DER data contains that text will vary.

Comment: grrr i dont have the file at hand but i remember there being a few extra bytes at the start at the file that get stripped when the file is converted to der.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what format your input file is in. There is more than one way to store a private key in a PEM file.

Comment: block 0-9f snippet....-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICdQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAl8wggJbAgEAAoGBANVDkSjrm8V5MnKk
FjWgSZy4bHHnHTVy3EdxrkR/NjD1mBgw9y+h
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` header you mention in your comment, indicates that you have a private key in PKCS8 format. Although it seems slightly strange to me. I would have expected the asn1parse output to look more like this:

```
    0:d=0  hl=4 l=1213 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :00
    7:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
    9:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   20:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
   22:d=1  hl=4 l=1191 prim: OCTET STRING
```

Note that you have no INTEGER field in your output.

You can use the openssl `pkcs8` utility to convert a PKCS8 file from PEM to DER

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in rsakey.pem -out rsakey.der -outform DER -nocrypt
```